# What is an example of a predense subset of a poset that contains no antichain?

Tags: set-theory, examples-counterexamples, order-theory, forcing

Let $\mathbb P = (P, ≤, 1)$ be a partial order.

We call an antichain $A$ of $P$ maximal
in case every $p ∈ P$ is compatible to some $a ∈ A$.

We say that a set $D ⊆ P$ is
predense in $P$ in case every $p ∈ P$ is compatible to some $d ∈ D$

(so - trivially -
an antichain of $P$ is maximal if and only if it is predense.)

Can someone give me an example of  a partial order $P$, and a predense subset $D$ of $P$, such
that no subset of $D$ is a maximal antichain of $P$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $P=\{1\}\sqcup(\omega\times\{0,1\})$, where $\omega\times\{0,1\}$ is partially ordered by saying $(m,i)\leq (n,0)$ iff $m\leq n$.  The set $D=\omega\times\{0\}$ is predense, since for any $(m,i)$, $(m,1)$ is a common extension of $(m,i)$ and the element $(m,0)\in D$.  But no subset of $D$ is a maximal antichain.  Indeed, $D$ is a chain, so any subset which is an antichain has at most one element.  But for any $(m,0)\in D$, $(n,1)$ is incompatible with $(m,0)$ for any $n>m$, so $\{(m,0)\}$ is not a maximal antichain.

Comment: Oh great! Thanks. I have just one small question regarding this max. antichain notion. Namely, if $D$ is dense subset of $P$, how can I show that then there is $A \subset D$; $A$ being maximal antichain of $P$..

Comment: Let $A$ be a maximal among all subsets of $D$ that are antichains, and show that $A$ is a maximal antichain of $P$.

Comment: @EricWofsey Could you elaborate on why a maximal antichain in $D$ (where $D$ is dense) should be a maximal antichain in $P$? For example if $P=\{0,a,b\}$ with $0\le a,b$, and $D=\{0,a\}$, then the antichain $\{a\}$ is maximal in $D$ but not $P$.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro: $\{a\}$ is a maximal antichain in $P$, since every element of $P$ has a common extension with $a$ (namely $0$).  In this context two elements are called "compatible" if there exists $c$ such that $c\leq a$ and $c\leq b$, not if they are comparable in the order.